# MOBO sees only half of the memory installed

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios, uefi

After a good amount of research I know that many similar questions to mine have been asked at least since 2005. What is amazing is that no good answers came forward throughout this time other than the typical "check for memory compatibility" (which I have already done)

Problem: I installed 32 GB of DDR3 RAM but BIOS and OS only sees half of it, i.e. 16 GB

**The kit:**

- Motherboard Asus M5A97 EVO R2.0 - Memory Dual Channel Architecture according to manual
- CPU: [AMD FX-4300](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/fx-4300) - dual channel capable with DDR3 up to 1866MHz
- Memory modules - 4 x [CML8GX3M2A 1600 c9](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/Memory/High-Performance-Memory/Vengeance%C2%AE-Low-Profile-%E2%80%94-8GB-Dual-Channel-DDR3-Memory-Kit/p/CML8GX3M2A1600C9)

**Tried so far:**

- Used pcpartpicker.com to reconfirm that the combination of MOBO, DDR and CPU are compatible with each other
- Tried each module independently in slot DIMMM_A2 (in each case I get 4 GB instead of 8 GB)
- Tried various combinations of 2 modules in slots DIMM_A2 and DIMM_B2 (in each case I get 8 GB instead of 16 GB)
- Changed UEFI/BIOS setting to disable ECC
- Changed UEFI/BIOS setting for memory speed to 1600MHz from the default 1333MHz

In all cases the system remains fully functional (I use Linux Mint) but obviously only has half of the expected memory.

My OS is 64 bit but remember that even UEFI/BIOS is reporting half before OS is loaded.

To me, it looks like even though everything is dual channel, only one channel is being used. But for the life of me I cannot find any setting in UEFI where this could be changed.

Comment: Its possible each memory slot only supports 4gig, asus support is down right now and I cannot confirm.

Comment: It is possible a bios upgrade can solve this issue also.

Comment: @Moab thank you for the suggestions but the BIOS is up to date and Asus manual says each slot can take up to 8 GB for a total of 32GB

Comment: The modules are not 8GB each but rather 4GB each sold in kits of 2. See [here](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/Memory/High-Performance-Memory/Vengeance®-Low-Profile-—-8GB-Dual-Channel-DDR3-Memory-Kit/p/CML8GX3M2A1600C9#tab-tech-specs).

Answer (score 3):

The solution is rather stupid: even though the sticker says 8G, in brackets it also says (2 x 4GB) and this is the modern marketing gimmick to tell you that the stick has only 4GB and that it belongs to a kit of two.  If you follow the Corsair link I provided in the original post and read very carefully then you will see the word kit there.

Now, I think the marketing guys are doing everything to be loved. Do you agree?

Comment: This is the only correct answer. See [this link, under specifications](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/Memory/High-Performance-Memory/Vengeance®-Low-Profile-—-8GB-Dual-Channel-DDR3-Memory-Kit/p/CML8GX3M2A1600C9#tab-tech-specs).

Answer (score 1):

I just read through the manual for your MOBO. It looks like on your MOBO next to the DIMM slots there should be a button called `MemOK!` as well as a light that says `DRAM_LED`.

https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketAM3+/M5A97_R2.0/E8046_M5A97_R2.pdf

Page 1-17 talks about this.

Also, it could be you need to flash update your BIOS. Could try clearing the RTCRAM.

Comment: What does this red button do?  When I see the LED next to mem-ok light up I press button and good stuff happens.  but seriously that looks like an answer to me,

Comment: @Jasen From reading through some of it, looks like it forces a memory compatibility tuning on the motherboard. It looks like it "loads and tests failsafe memory settings". Essentially a memory recovery tool!

Comment: @lost_admin Thanks for the suggestions. I have done both (and a few more that occurred to me) but so far nothing. These memory sticks say on the label 8GB (2 x 4GB) which I find a very strange notation but maybe it means 4GB per channel.

Comment: @quiet-ranger the label saying 2x4GB leads me to think that they are 4GB per stick together to make 8. Which would explain why you’re only showing 16- because it really is 16. Unfortunate that is

Comment: @lost_admin I think you are right.  The spec on the Corsair site even says "kit", so it belongs to a pair that together make up 8GB. What a waste of time...thanks man

Comment: @quiet-ranger that’s such a shame. I feel for you man, it sucks.